# LINQ Select distinct from a List?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following list:

```
    class Person
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public String City { get; set; }

        public Person(String name, String lastName, String city)
        {
            Name = name;
            LastName = lastName;
            City = city;
        }
    }

    ...

    personList.Add(new Person("a", "b", "1"));
    personList.Add(new Person("c", "d", "1"));
    personList.Add(new Person("e", "f", "2"));
    personList.Add(new Person("g", "h", "1"));
    personList.Add(new Person("i", "j", "2"));
    personList.Add(new Person("k", "l", "1"));
```

How do I retrieve a list of persons differing from the city name?

Expecting Results:

An Array/Collection of lists (persons) differing from the city name:

```
result[0] = List<Person> where city name = "1"
result[1] = List<Person> where city name = "2"
result[n] = List<Person> where city name = "whatever"
```

Comment: Do you mean where LastName != City ?

Comment: No, I wan't a list containing all the Persons that contains 1 as a city and another that contains 2 as a city...

Comment: Are you trying to group the person's by city?

Comment: I'm also confused. Did you want a count of people by city, or to group them by city?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use LINQ to group the persons list by city:

```
var groupedPersons = personList.GroupBy(x => x.City);
foreach (var g in groupedPersons)
{
    string city = g.Key;
    Console.WriteLine(city);
    foreach (var person in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", person.Name, person.LastName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Darin Dimitrov's answer, here is the same in query syntax:

```
var groupByCityQuery = from person in personList 
                       group person by person.City into grouping 
                       select grouping;
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this comment: No, I wan't a list containing all the Persons that contains 1 as a city and another that contains 2 as a city...

We can do something like this:

```
var city1People = personList.Where(x => x.city == "1").ToList();
var city2People = personList.Where(x => x.city == "2").ToList();
```

if this is something more dynamic, like you're going to have N cities and want an individual list of people per city, you're going to need to return a collection of lists.

Comment: How can I do this dinamically?