# Get distinct values from list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
    public List<MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER> GetEmployeeTransferListForHR(TimecardDataContext TimecardDC)
    {
        List<MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER> objEmployeeTransferList = null;
        try
        {
            objEmployeeTransferList = new List<MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER>();
            objEmployeeTransferList = TimecardDC.MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER.Where(
                employee =>
                    employee.HR_ADMIN_IND=="Y").ToList();                
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return objEmployeeTransferList;
    }
```

It shows all list of values where hr admin indicator=yes. But I have to get `hr admin=yes` and distinct(empid) from the table `MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER`. How to get distinct `empId` from the the `objEmployeeTransferList`.

Comment: Try doing  `groupby`empId and then selecting. have a look [LINQ Select distinct from a List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572006/linq-select-distinct-from-a-list) will help you

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912188/linq-distinct-by-name-for-populate-a-dropdown-list-with-name-and-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<int> ids = objEmployeeTransferList
                   .Select(e => e.empId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

Also you can make this on server side without creating in-memory employee list with all admin records:

```
List<int> ids = TimecardDC.MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER
                   .Where(e => e.HR_ADMIN_IND == "Y")
                   .Select(e => e.empId)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: After getting that list from objEmployeeTransferList. And then only i have to filter by distict(empid). how i have to do that.

Comment: @SaiAyyappsSekaran first sample gets unique ids from objEmployeeTransferList

Answer (score 6):

Have try making it

```
.Distinct().ToList();
```

You can refer here [LINQ: Distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values)

Comment: it is not working for me . i want do same in C# object list .

Answer (score 3):

Get Distinct using GroupBy

```
objEmployeeTransferList.GroupBy(x => x.empId).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try:

```
objEmployeeTransferList = TimecardDC.MAS_EMPLOYEE_TRANSFER.Where(
   employee => employee.HR_ADMIN_IND=="Y").Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinct method in linq which should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb348436.aspx