# Get all DISTINCT items in the List with LINQ

Tags: c#

I am quite new to LINQ, I have the following script which returns me the first item in the table if condition meets, however, I would like to get all distinct items not only the first one. I am relatively new on this platform.

```
public LG GetLG (int WID)
{
    lock (locker) {
      return database.Table<LG> ().FirstOrDefault (x => x.id == WID);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property/491832#491832

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get distinct values from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086438/get-distinct-values-from-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `.Distinct()` what you're looking for?

```
return database.Table<LG>.Where(x => x.id == WID).Distinct()
```

The following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) contains useful material:

Example:

```
List<int> ages = new List<int> { 21, 46, 46, 55, 17, 21, 55, 55 };

IEnumerable<int> distinctAges = ages.Distinct();

Console.WriteLine("Distinct ages:");

foreach (int age in distinctAges)
{
  Console.WriteLine(age);
}
```

This code produces the following output:

> Distinct ages:
>   21
>   46
>   55
>   17

Comment: you'll need to override the 'Equals' and the 'GetHashCode' methods

Answer (score -1):

in your `LG` object, you'll need to override the `Equals` and the `GetHashCode` methods.
Once you've done that, you can use the `Distinct()` function in LINQ

```
database.Table<LG>.Where(x => x.id == WID).Distinct()
```