# Check for duplicates before adding, or just select distinct when finished?

Tags: c#

**Problem:** Building a `List<string>`, by adding strings one-by-one iteratively. The end result needs to be the `List<string>` with no duplicates.

**1)** When adding strings to the list, check if the string is already there using `myList.Contains(myString)` and if not then `myList.Add(myString)`. The end result will have no duplicates but the list is checked every time.

**2)** Just `myList.Add(myString)` without any care, without checking the list each time, then when needed, use some technique to effectively `SELECT DISTINCT` from the list. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572073/1061602 - that answer would be tweaked as the end result would need to be just a `List<string>`

**Q:** Which would be the best approach in terms of efficiency and readability (1, 2 or something else?).

The `List<string>` would not be excessively large, but could end up containing around 10 strings, with around 200 checks. This could scale up to around 30 strings with around 600 checks.

Comment: Use `HashSet<string>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx, the `Add` method returns a `bool` telling you if something was added or not.

Comment: Does it have to be a list?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a list, will look into HashSet, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach would be to use a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead, which will "eat up" duplicates transparently. When using a set the "check if duplicate" operation is not only automatic but also much faster than when using a list (constant time vs linear).

If your string consumer can consume `IEnumerable<string>` that's all you will need to do; otherwise, use `Enumerable.ToList` to convert the set to a list.

Comment: Thats the way to do it. Jon not Skeet ;-). But you are catching up.

Answer (score 1):

in your scenario you should use Hashset, as it would give you O(1) for checking containment. Wheras List will do it O(n) unless it is sorted.